# How to properly hit POST endpoint

Tags: node.js, express

In my node / express app I need to handle GET and POST api request to

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products
```

The GET request goes through just fine, but the POST request is not even hitting the endpoint, and I don't understand why. When I try to hit POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products with postman, I get

```
{
    "message": "The user is not authorized"
}
```

I try to set breakpoints in the "products" route - the one handling GET is being hit, the one handling POST is not.

Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv/config');
const authJwt = require('./helpers/jwt');
const errorHandler = require('./helpers/error-handler');


app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors())

//middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(authJwt());
app.use('/public/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/public/uploads'));
app.use(errorHandler);

//Routes
const categoriesRoutes = require('./routes/categories');
const productsRoutes = require('./routes/products');
const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users');
const ordersRoutes = require('./routes/orders');

const api = process.env.API_URL;

app.use(`${api}/categories`, categoriesRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/products`, productsRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/users`, usersRoutes);
app.use(`${api}/orders`, ordersRoutes);

//Database
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    dbName: 'eshopdb'
})
.then(()=>{
    console.log('Database Connection is ready...')
})
.catch((err)=> {
    console.log(err);
})

//Server
app.listen(3000, ()=>{

    console.log('server is running http://localhost:3000');
})
```

Here is my 'products' route:

```
const {Product} = require('../models/product');
const express = require('express');
const { Category } = require('../models/category');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');

const FILE_TYPE_MAP = {
    'image/png': 'png',
    'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
    'image/jpg': 'jpg'
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        const isValid = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        let uploadError = new Error('invalid image type');

        if(isValid) {
            uploadError = null
        }
      cb(uploadError, 'public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        
      const fileName = file.originalname.split(' ').join('-');
      const extension = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
      cb(null, `${fileName}-${Date.now()}.${extension}`)
    }
  })
  
const uploadOptions = multer({ storage: storage })

router.get(`/`, async (req, res) =>{
    let filter = {};
    if(req.query.categories)
    {
         filter = {category: req.query.categories.split(',')}
    }

    const productList = await Product.find(filter).populate('category');

    if(!productList) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send(productList);
})

router.get(`/:id`, async (req, res) =>{
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).populate('category');

    if(!product) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send(product);
})

router.post(`/`, uploadOptions.single('image'), async (req, res) =>{
    const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
    if(!category) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Category')

    const file = req.file;
    if(!file) return res.status(400).send('No image in the request')

    const fileName = file.filename
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;
    let product = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
        image: `${basePath}${fileName}`,// "http://localhost:3000/public/upload/image-2323232"
        brand: req.body.brand,
        price: req.body.price,
        category: req.body.category,
        countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
        isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured,
    })

    product = await product.save();

    if(!product) 
    return res.status(500).send('The product cannot be created')

    res.send(product);
})



router.put('/:id',async (req, res)=> {
    if(!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)) {
       return res.status(400).send('Invalid Product Id')
    }
    const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
    if(!category) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Category')

    const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        {
            name: req.body.name,
            description: req.body.description,
            richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
            image: req.body.image,
            brand: req.body.brand,
            price: req.body.price,
            category: req.body.category,
            countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
            rating: req.body.rating,
            numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
            isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured,
        },
        { new: true}
    )

    if(!product)
    return res.status(500).send('the product cannot be updated!')

    res.send(product);
})

router.delete('/:id', (req, res)=>{
    Product.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).then(product =>{
        if(product) {
            return res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'the product is deleted!'})
        } else {
            return res.status(404).json({success: false , message: "product not found!"})
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
       return res.status(500).json({success: false, error: err}) 
    })
})

router.get(`/get/count`, async (req, res) =>{
    const productCount = await Product.countDocuments((count) => count)

    if(!productCount) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send({
        productCount: productCount
    });
})

router.get(`/get/featured/:count`, async (req, res) =>{
    const count = req.params.count ? req.params.count : 0
    const products = await Product.find({isFeatured: true}).limit(+count);

    if(!products) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send(products);
})

router.put(
    '/gallery-images/:id', 
    uploadOptions.array('images', 10), 
    async (req, res)=> {
        if(!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)) {
            return res.status(400).send('Invalid Product Id')
         }
         const files = req.files
         let imagesPaths = [];
         const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;

         if(files) {
            files.map(file =>{
                imagesPaths.push(`${basePath}${file.filename}`);
            })
         }

         const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {
                images: imagesPaths
            },
            { new: true}
        )

        if(!product)
            return res.status(500).send('the gallery cannot be updated!')

        res.send(product);
    }
)

module.exports =router;
```

What can I change in order to hit the POST endpoint handler?

Comment: What's in the authJwt middleware? That looks significant

Comment: can you show us the content of `authJwt()`? I suspect the request isn't even reaching the post endpoint. can you also console.log to confirm?

Comment: you both are correct - authJwt was the culprit.